# How do I run ccleaner when using Hirens Boot CD?

Tags: bootable-media, livecd, ccleaner, hiren

I just tried running it and it was analyzing the Hiren CD, how do I analyze my main drive while using Hirens boot cd?

Comment: Why is running CCleaner of all things from a LiveCD so important? What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Karan I think he is desperately trying to "de-crapify" his computer..

Comment: @oldmud0: But why with a LiveCD? If he thinks it'll magically repair a broken Windows install or something he's sadly mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You only use CCleaner on the Windows that you are currently working off of. If you start CCleaner on a live CD, then CCleaner will try to clean up your live CD's Windows instead of your main drive's Windows.

You must start Windows on your main drive and run CCleaner from the launcher in your CD once you've reached that point.